# Default item in bound ComboBox

Tags: wpf, styles

I have a bound `ComboBox` where I need to show default item "No Selection". `ComboBox` should close with no text selection and no selected item, When the user selects this option ("No Selection") from list.

These are the data resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:iTimeKeepBaseDataSet x:Key="iTimeKeepBaseDataSet" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="codeSetsViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=codeSets, Source={StaticResource iTimeKeepBaseDataSet}}" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="allMattersViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=allMatters, Source={StaticResource iTimeKeepBaseDataSet}}" />
    <my:CodeIdToDetailsConverter x:Key="codeIdDetailsConverter" />

</UserControl.Resources>
```

This is ComboBox data template

```
                  <DataTemplate x:Key="CodeSetDataCellEditTemplate">
                        <ComboBox DataContext="{StaticResource codeSetsViewSource}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                  SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=codeSetId}"
                                  SelectionChanged="OnCodeSetsSelectionChanged"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboboxTemplate}">

                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>

                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
                                                <Binding Path="codeSetId" />
                                                <Binding Path="codeSetName" />
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

Template column of DataGrid

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="codeSetId1Column"
                                        Width="SizeToHeader"
                                        CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource CodeSetDataCellEditTemplate}"
                                        Header="Code Set ID 1"
                                        my:DataGridAttachedProperty.ColumnName="codeSetId1">
```

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompositeCollection

```
    <CompositeCollection>
       <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Black">Select Item</ComboBoxItem>
       <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataKey}}" />    
    </CompositeCollection>
```

But, you can't use Binding here, workaround is to use [BindingProxy](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/) with CompositeCollection

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188402/combobox-with-empty-item) here and comments for more details

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I'll try and let you.