# Append custom value to a LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this LINQ2SQL statement:

```
var value = from o in DataContext.Table
            where o.Active == "Yes"
            orderby o.Name
            select o;
```

I'd like to append a new Name to this list (i.e. "Select Option 4");

I'm not sure how I can accomplish this (if I can)?

value could have:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
```

I also want to be able to add:

```
Select Option 4
```

Comment: what you mean `append new Name`? you want insert it to db?

Comment: no...  I just want it at the end of the list.  See my updated question

Comment: Do u need this for displaying purposes only? E.g. to display in a control?

Comment: yes display only - in a combo box

Comment: @webdad3 then don't do it in this LINQ statement/value. Add "Please Select" directly to combobox items - it does not belong with the data

Comment: @YuriyGalanter - The combobox is bound to the value(s) from this statement.  How would I go about doing it differently?

Comment: @webdad3 you can have both bound and manual items in combobox. Which one is it - ASP.NET?

Comment: See for example this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188402/combobox-with-empty-item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = (from o in DataContext.Table
            where o.Active == "Yes"
            orderby o.Name
            select o).AsEnumerable()
                     .Concat(new [] { new TableObject() });
```

Of course, it will not change your database content at all.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me?  How does the TableObject add my value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Concat` to concat another sequence, and then just put the one item you want into its own sequence:

```
value = value.Concat(new[]{"Select a different Option"});
```

If this is something you do often enough you can create an extension method to handle it for you:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T item)
{
    return source.Concat(new[] { item });
}
```