# CollectionContainer doesn't bind my Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have something like a form where the user can assign a cutomer to a vehicle. But this is optional. The customers are in a combobox. I need a way to make sure that the user can choose 'none' if the combobox is open.

if have found something like this:

```
<ComboBox.ItemsSource>    
    <CompositeCollection>
       <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Foreground="Black">none</ComboBoxItem>
       <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataKey}}" />    
    </CompositeCollection>
</ComboBox.ItemsSource>
```

But the Binding to the Collection doesn't work for me.

My form is an userControl which is included in a WPF-Window. The DataContext is on a Grid in the Window. Therefore, I have tried:

```
<CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Customers, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}" />
```

But the comboBox only shows 'none'. How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried binding against `DataContext.Customers` in your second binding?

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Yes, I have tried this: DataContext.Customers, Source={Relative ....}

Comment: use output panel to see if theb binding was successful or not.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa I have some errors but I don't know how to fix this: 'DataContext' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource', ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='ComboBoxItem'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you took the code here: [ComboBox with empty item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188402/combobox-with-empty-item)

The answer says that the binding won't work, as it has no access. Use `BindingProxy` if you want to fix it: http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: I have found a solution on this page:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc8fc068-5f3e-4179-be8b-b6b4c50803ff/how-to-use-collectioncontainer-as-itemssource?forum=wpf