# Add new item into my ComboBox lead to ItemsSource. Exception

Tags: wpf, binding

i have `ComboBox` binding with my `collection` and now i want to add another `Item` before the binding: `"Please select..."`
So i try this:

```
combobox.Items.Add("Please select");
```

But because i have this dinging:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> collection { get; set; }
```

`ItemsSource="{Binding collection}"`

All i received is this error:

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource

So how can i solve it ?

Comment: Did you google it? There are a lot of possible solutions of your problem.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1188447/1648849).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are binding to an ItemsSource, you cannot manually update the items in the combobox as this would invalidate the binding. If you want another value in your ItemsSource, just add it to "collection" in your ViewModel.