# WPF - Detect design mode in a Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have a converter in which I want to be able to change the value to Visibility.Collapsed when in DesignMode. Right it is ignoring the GetIsInDesignMode.

Also, I am binding the VM via dependency injectio (prism)

**Converter:**

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            return Visibility.Collapsed;

        if (value != null && value is AllowedSourceCode)
        {
            var allowedSourceCode = (AllowedSourceCode)value;

            if (value == null)
                return Visibility.Visible;
            else if (allowedSourceCode.SupportedSourceCodes.Contains(allowedSourceCode.SelectedSourceCode))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            return Visibility.Visible;

        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

**View:**

```
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding SupportedSourceCodes,Converter={StaticResource AllowedSourcesConverter}}" Background="Gray" Opacity="0.9"
            Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Panel.ZIndex="5"  >
```

**xaml.cs:**

```
        public ACARSubLedgerUC(ACARSubLedgerVM vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
```

Comment: That is the normal way to do it. Please clarify your question. Provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem. Include a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. Saying "it doesn't seem to work" is not a useful problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing should work.

I'm guessing you have a viewmodel behind your window and using the converter on a binding to that viewmodel. Please make sure you are setting your data context in XAML and not in code, because if you are setting it in code your converter will never hit in design mode.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    ...

</Window>
```

This ensures bindings are updated at design time and hence your converter will be called.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a markup extension that makes it way easier to muck around with design time bindings and property values without messing around with the code your view binds to or changing the actual runtime value of a property. The full write up is here: http://www.singulink.com/CodeIndex/post/wpf-visibility-binding-with-design-time-control

It works with visibility as well as most other properties. Usage looks like:

```
<Grid Visibility="{data:Value {Binding RootObject, Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}, DesignValue=Visible}">
    <TextBlock Background="Red" Text="Testing visibility" />
</Grid>
```

The extension class:

```
public class ValueExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public object DesignValue { get; set; } = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    [ConstructorArgument("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; } = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

    public ValueExtension() { }

    public ValueExtension(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var provideValueTarget = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;
        var target = provideValueTarget.TargetObject as FrameworkElement;

        var value = DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(target) && DesignValue != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ? DesignValue : Value;

        if (value == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || value == null)
            return value;

        if (value is MarkupExtension)
        {
            return ((MarkupExtension)value).ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
        }

        var property = provideValueTarget.TargetProperty as DependencyProperty;

        if (property.PropertyType.IsInstanceOfType(value))
            return value;


        return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType).ConvertFrom(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind pasting in the code here? There are too many dead links in answers on SO, all of which were reasonably expected to be around indefinitely. Also: Very cool markup extension.

Comment: Makes sense, dead links on here are incredible annoying.